# Winform application cant access database on 64 bit operating system

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I made a win-form application in C#.It runs on 32-bit operating Windows Operating System  and can normally access my database but when it runs onto 64-bit,my database cant be accessed. What i am using is listed below:

```
Visual stdio 2010 ;;
SQL Server Compact[version 3.5.1.50] ;;
Html agility Pack[version  1.4.6.0] ;;
```

When i run my app onto 64 bit Operating System then my app runs but i cant access database.
How can i solve this ? Is there any suggestion??
Is there any compability issue of Html agility Pack[version  1.4.6.0] for 64 bit????

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: It says "Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll'. The specified module could not be found"

Comment: Compile the .exe to target x86 instead of AnyCPU (and make sure SQL Server Compact is installed on the x64 machine)

Comment: Is there any compability issue of Html agility Pack[version  1.4.6.0] for 64 bit????

Comment: it didn't work as the way you said.is there is other solution @ErikEJ

Comment: Yes, see my blog here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: but i am using compact 3.5 what about 3.5??? @ErikEJ

Comment: "Google" my blog - http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html

Comment: I followed your blog but it shows when i run in 64 bit --->"Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll'. The specified module could not be found"